# Finding left and right side of line in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

i have road layer as line and polygon layer as building,i want to know left and right side of road in relation with buildings

Is it possible in ArcGIS for Desktop?

[image]

Comment: If you are looking for an ArcGIS for Desktop Answer can you edit your Question to add an `arcgis-desktop` and a tag for the version you are using (e.g. `arcgis-10.2`), please?  Also, more explanation of how you want to determine which is left and right on your streets will also be helpful.

Comment: Programmatically it is possible, but that depends on your road's orientation being correct.

Answer (score 1):

in ArcGIS, you can use linear referencing

First, create points at the center of your polygons

Second, you "[creates routes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000005000000)" from your streets in order to have "M aware" polylines. CreateRoutes_lr (in_line_features, route_id_field, out_feature_class, "LENGTH")

Third, you locate your points along the route in order to extract the M value

the sign of the offset value will tell you on which side of the road you are.

Comment: can you elaborate create routs?

Comment: actually i want to find orientation of buildings in referance to roads.i tried identify tool but dosnt give any result..

Comment: in that case, if you replace buildings by beaches and roads by coastlines, the question is somewhat similar to this one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94424/how-to-query-osm-for-all-beaches-facing-west-qgis-preferred . Note how in that thread it's referred as 'west' and 'east' - is that what you meant with left and right?. Unlike waterways where it's common to watch down the stream to determine left and right, there's no such standard conventions for roads. However in a GIS-file you know in what direction it was drawn. Up to you to judge if your data allows such use.